# Calculate within multiple where clause mysql

Tags: mysql, store

I have database structure as shown in the picture (it's simplified)[image: simplified database structure]

so now i want to calculate products in all stocks so that the result looked like (this assuming that store table has two records of store1 and store2):

[image]

if this is not possible this format is acceptable too

[image]

The main problem is that i can't figure out how should i calculate current stock for each store.

```
the curent stock for each stock =  sum of all productin this stock
                                 - sum of all productout this stock
                                 + sum of all producttransfer with transfertype=0 in this stock 
                                 - sum of all producttransfer with transfertype=1 in this stock
```

so how should i calculate it for each store when store number is not fixed

Comment: This is a really unususal design for a stock system. Are you able to change the design (at least a bit)? If I understand it correctly, you added/have a table for every type of stock change, where you could and should actually just add a column with a type (you can still have the additional tables for additional specific information, although its not necessary), and, maybe, a column for the store too, but I guess that would not fit to your design idea. Your model feels like a store added to a really generic action model that was not meant to be a store.

Comment: Otherwise, you can left join all your action tables, group by the store and then use `sum(case when productin.id is null then actiondetails.Quantity else 0 end) + sum(case when productout.id then -actiondetails.Quantity else 0 end) + ...` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work, I'm writting it on the go so can't be 100% sure and there might be some typos

```
    select A1.ProductID, A1.storehouseID, (SUM(IN)-SUM(OUT)) as quantity
    from (
          Select AD.productID, A.storehouseID, SUM(AD.Quantity) as IN
          from actions A inner join productIN PI on A.ID = PI.ID
                         inner join actiondetails AD on PI.ID = AD.ID
    group by AD.productID, A.storehouseID

    UNION

           select AD.ProductID, A.storehouseID, SUM(AD.Quantity)
           from actions A inner join ProductTransfers T on A.ID = T.ID
                          inner join actiondetails AD on A.ID = AD.ID
           where transferType = 0
           group by AD.ProductID, A.storehouseID) as A1 

                                                        inner join 

          (select AD.productID, A.storehouseID, SUM(AD.Quantity) as Out
           from actions A inner join ProductOut PO on A.ID = PO.ID
                          inner join actiondetails AD on AD.ID = A.ID
           group by AD.ProductID, A.storehouseID

     UNION

           select AD.productID, A.storehouse.ID, SUM(AD.Quantity) as Out
           from actions A inner join ProductTransfers T on A.ID = T.ID
                          inner join actiondetails AD on AD.ID = A.ID
           where TransferType = 1
           group by AD.ProductID, A.storehouseID) as A2  
           on A1.ProductID = A2.ProductID and A1.storehouseID = A2.storehouseID
     group by A1.ProductID, A1.StorehouseID
```